# Trying to Rebuild a Legacy IOS App, Getting Error in Facebook-IOS-SDK Cocoapod

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, facebook-ios-sdk

I've been asked to rebuild an existing IOS app that uses Facebook-IOS-SDK.  The app is at least 5 years old so I expected things to be deprecated.   I have some limited experience with XCode and IOS but I'm far from an expert.  I've never used cocapods until today.   I installed cocoapods and ran pod init.  Facebook-IOS-SDK ver 3.24.4 loaded with no errors (other pods too, including Bolt, with no errors).

I've read the migration notes [on the FB dev page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4x/) regarding the versions and it's implied that I should be able to use 3.24.  When I do a clean build I get the error:

```
(FBRequest *)requestForUpdateOpenGraphObject(id<FBOpenGraphObject>)object 
{
    return [FBRequest requestForUpdateOpenGraphObjectWithId:object[@"id"] graphObject:object];
}

Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'id<FBOpenGraphObject>'
```

This error is in FBRequest.m, the cocoapod code, not in my clients code.  This code is marked read only.  If this *is* the correct pod version, and I can't change it then is there some other dependency in the (large) project that needs to be updated?

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, "9.0"
target "tbd" do
   pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
   pod 'UICKeyChainStore'
   pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 2.0.0-beta'
   pod 'SDURLCache'
   pod 'HockeySDK'
   pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.23'
   pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK'
   pod 'UIActionSheet-Blocks', '~> 1.0'
end

target "tbdTests" do

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only, nasty, solution I found is to change the code inside FBRequest.m manually.

Change line 370 from:

```
return [FBRequest requestForUpdateOpenGraphObjectWithId:object[@"id"] graphObject:object];
```

to

```
return [FBRequest requestForUpdateOpenGraphObjectWithId:object.objectID graphObject:object];
```

this should make you project runs again.

Again, this is not a nice solution, but it works :)
Emilio

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have the need to use Facebook-IOS-SDK ver 3.24.4 you can simply use the latest version 4.36.0.

have a look at your Podfile and see if there is any reference to Facebook-IOS-SDK, if there is something like:

```
pod 'Facebook-IOS-SDK', '~> 3.0'
```

you can replace it with:

```
pod 'Facebook-IOS-SDK', '~> 4.0'
```

otherwise post your Podfile and we can have a look.

Cheers

Comment: Yes, this app does need the FB api.  I have edited my question to include the podfile.   I enabled IOS 9.0, cleaned and rebuilt with facebook-ios-sdk ver 3.24 and the same error.   It's my understanding that I *cannot* upgrade to ~> 4.0 without code changes.   I would like to stay with 3.24 if possible.